# Why doesn't my Area 51 discussion show in the proposal page?

Tags: support, area-51

I posted [this question](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/q/26/2927) regarding [this proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/20517/game-recommendations), but the proposal page doesn't link back. Why is that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It can take a minute or two for Area 51 to get notified of the new post.  If enough people are confused by this, I suppose we'll have to figure out how to make it faster!

Answer (score 1):

It does for me.

I can see the question vote count, answer count and title and they all link back to the question.

The vote count was off at first so there must be some caching involved.